# I'm trying to deploy my nodejs app on GCP, but I keep getting Error: Cannot find module '../models/postModel'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, filepath

To preface this, everything works fine on my local machine running nodejs. I've found different stackoverflow questions in a similar nature, but not this specific issue - also everything that pertained to it within those questions I was already doing correctly. When I deploy to Google Cloud Platform and perform 'npm start', then check the logs I'm greeted the following error:

```
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  Error: Cannot find module '../models/postModel'
```

```
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  Error: Cannot find module '../models/postModel'
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  Require stack:
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  - /workspace/controllers/defaultController.js
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  - /workspace/routes/defaultRoutes.js
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  - /workspace/app.js
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/controllers/defaultController.js:5:14)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/routes/defaultRoutes.js:4:27)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]    requireStack: [
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      '/workspace/controllers/defaultController.js',
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      '/workspace/routes/defaultRoutes.js',
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]      '/workspace/app.js'
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]    ]
2021-08-03 09:39:37 default[20210803t053754]  }
```

I've attempted to reupload the repo, I've made some changes to the package.json as well as added the app.yaml file. I cannot for the life of me understand why I'm getting this error, and I can only presume its GCP not recognizing my file paths - but the tech support I was in contact with said that's most likely not the problem, and that it's more code level.
I'll provide the package.json, my app.yaml & the first few lines of my app.js below as well:

Most important: (where the bug is actually appearing at)

defaultController.js

```
//[Config]
const config = require('../config/configuration');

//[Import Schema]
const Post = require('../models/postModel');
const Event = require('../models/EventModel');
const Category = require('../models/CategoryModel');
const Carou = require('../models/CarouselModel');
const User = require('../models/UserModel').User;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Vicious Website",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Nodejs Website/Webapp, front & back end",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/viciousinsight/website-dev.git"
  },
  "author": "NJL",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/viciousinsight/website-dev/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/viciousinsight/website-dev#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.4.1",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "flash": "^1.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
```

app.js (first few lines

```
//[Special Global Variables]
const {globalVariables} = require('./config/configuration');
const {selectOption} = require('./config/customFunctions');

//[Imports]
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

//[Database & Sensitive] It's a secret to everybody
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {mongoDbUrl, PORT} = require('./config/configuration'); 
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const passport = require('passport');

//[Start Everything]
const app = express();
```

I'm still fairly new to nodejs and Google Cloud Platform, and I'm sorta at the end of my rope on this one, so any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: if u can post a screenshot of your file hierarchy then I can help, Also let me know how you have exported your module '../models/postModel'

Comment: Can you add a few details on how you are deploying? Are you deploying to app engine? How are you deploying, through cloud build, the gcloud app deploy command, something else? In what env are you manually running npm start, that wouldn't be necessary in app engine.

Comment: I discovered the issue, it was getting hung on two instances where it was misnamed. Please excuse this bug, I'm still somewhat new to GCP and misunderstood the error, and misattributed it to GCP. Thank you for taking the time to consider this question

Comment: So your issue is resolved. That's nice. Thank you for the update. Much appreciated.